# how to compare two content type fields and filter the output by drupal views?

Tags: views

I have two content types.

```
*content_type1
*content_type2 [set as content profile]
```

In `content_type1`, I have a taxonomy term [user has to choose any one of term] and `content_type2` has cck select list field with same terms as `content_type2`.

I created two roles:

```
*role1 users can create content_type1             
*role2 users can create content_type2
```

Now I want to display list of `content_type1`s in user `role2` profile page whose "select field  Value" is as same as the "taxonomy term " of `content_type1`.

How can I implement this using drupal views?

Comment: It seems you need panels rather than Views to acomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're going to need this:

[views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6)  inside of the **user_profile.tpl.php**

more specifically:

First set up a view to return content type 1 nodes, that takes an argument of taxonomy term id.

Then, assuming you can get the content type 2 node into user_profile.tpl.php, grab the select list value like so:

```
<?php
    $selected_value = $content_type2_node->field_selectlistname[0]['value'];
    $term_id = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($selected_value);

?>
```

note use of [taxonomy_get_term_by_name()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/6)

and use of a cck select list field named is field_selectlistname, update that to your field name.

then you can use this:

```
<?php
   print views_embed_view("view_name","block_1",$term_id);
?>
```

to print out your view.

Note that the first two arguments are the view name of your view, and the display id, which is going to be something like 'block_1', 'default' or 'page_1'

I'm assuming here you know how to set up the view, and know how to get that user_profile.tpl.php to work for your role.. (if isset($account->roles[ role id ])... )

good luck!